# How to work with vue.js and window.getSelection()?

Tags: vue.js, selection, contenteditable

Here is an example from some tutorial:

```
<p id="p">Example: <i>italic</i> and <b>bold</b></p>

<script>
  let range = new Range();

  range.setStart(p.firstChild, 2);
  range.setEnd(p.querySelector('b').firstChild, 3);

  alert(range); // ample: italic and bol

  // use this range for selection (explained later)
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);
</script>
```

How to do this with vue?

Should I use query selectors too?

I am interested how to do this selection manipulation within contenteditable. I can use "ref" for contenteditable container but inner content with bold, italic etc. tags is dynamic and mark this code with refs:

```
... <b><i>some text</i></b> ...
```

isn't appropriate.

Comment: Could you show what you have tried? Vue doesn't replace basic DOM api's so window.getSelection should work just fine. And please narrow down to a specific question.

Comment: @AlexMA, What dou you mean "narrow down"? I have asked "How to do this with vue?" and have shown an example of code in vanilla javascript.

Comment: @AlexMA. I didn't try anything with vue and window.getSelection() because I don't know where to start that is why I have asked this question.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @AlexMA, I am not aware about any vue components that use window.getSelection(). There are only wrappers to contenteditable tags.

Comment: This question isn't really applicable to Vue because Vue provides no mechanism for manipulating selections. As long as you have a reference to the DOM element you want to manipulate (and that DOM element isn't managed by Vue) then you can use the selection APIs as described from that tutorial. Can you clarify what is Vue-specific about this question?

Comment: @DecadeMoon, Should I use query selectors too? Using `p.querySelector('b').firstChild` isn't vue way but I don't know what should I use instead.

Comment: @DecadeMoon, I want to work with caret and selection in vue in contenteditable tag. I need to get selected text, I need to get position of the caret and place it where I need but this will be too broad a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the Selection API to manipulate the DOM (not just creating ranges, but adding/removing/modifing/reordering DOM nodes), then you should be doing those manipulations on DOM elements not managed by Vue. You must not modify parts of the DOM managed by Vue because Vue won't know about those changes and it will get confused when trying to patch the DOM during the next render cycle. Vue "owns" the rendered DOM of its components.

This doesn't mean you can't use the Selection API and Vue together, it just means you need to be careful not to tinker in the DOM willy-nilly.

> Should I use query selectors too? Using p.querySelector('b').firstChild isn't vue way but I don't know what should I use insted

This rule only applies if you want to get a reference to a DOM node rendered by Vue. If the container were content editable, then its contents would not be managed by Vue and you would have no way of referencing its contents without using `querySelector` and other DOM functions. Try not to get caught up with "am I doing it the Vue-way?" when what you are trying to do is inherently not Vue related anyway.

Comment: I don't want to to change DOM structure of contenteditable tag with vue in vanilla javascript way. I only need select children nodes to figure out where is a caret and if it isn't within text node to put it into the closes text node. I want to intercept all keys and mouse default actions (keydown, click etc.) and put characters into vue state and after it vue should rerender contentediteble container. I was trying to understand how prosemirror and draft-js working. It looks like they use the same concept.